# I am creating an Ecom using react and I am unable to render the product details, console is showing no errors

Tags: reactjs, get, localhost, mern

I am trying to render productdetails on the local server but it is not rendering the details from the backend, Tried passing using useparams method but the console brings up with undefined params error. here is my code,

Productdetails.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from "../../actions/productAction";

const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching product details...");
    if (match && match.params.id) {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
    }
  }, [dispatch, match]);

  console.log("Product details: ", product);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{product && product.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

productactions.js

```
import axios from "axios";

import {
  ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
  ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

export const getProduct = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/products");

    dispatch({
      type: ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};

export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.product,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
//CLEARING ERROR
export const clearErrors = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
};
```

I was trying to render the product details but failed to do despite the console showing no errors

Comment: Are you sure your action is called?

Comment: yes i tried editing the actions but it did not worked